# Finding participant of a Google+ hangout given its URL

Tags: api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I'd like to find out who is participating in a particular hangout given its URL. Of course, I'll be using my login credentials, and I'll be able to do that only if I can actually join the hangout.

How can I do that programmatically? I didn't find anything in the Hangouts API. As far as I understand, to use the Hangouts API, you must join a specific hangout, you can't just use it on an arbitrary hangout URL.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - the Hangout URL will not tell you who is in a Hangout. The Hangout ID is both arbitrary and anonymous. Also, the people in a Hangout change so rapidly, getting that list wouldn't be accurate.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can get participants in a Hangout if they install your Hangout App.